# Configure Nginx to reply to http://my-domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/XXXX

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm not able to get nginx to return the files I've put in `/var/www/letsencrypt`.

**nginx/sites-available/mydomain.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name my-real-domain.com;

  include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

  root /var/www/mydomain;
  index index.html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

**nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf**

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
  default_type "text/plain";
  root /var/www/letsencrypt;
}
```

I run this command:
**certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/letsencrypt/ -d my-real-domain.com**

But the page that certbot tries to access is always an 404.

**DEBUGGING**

```
$ echo hi > /var/www/letsencrypt/hi
$ chmod 644 /var/www/letsencrypt/hi
```

Now I should be able to `curl localhost/.well-known/acme-challenge/hi`, but that does not work. Still 404. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You could try In case you still want to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53134710/5985566

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/876137/how-to-set-up-http-based-domain-validation-on-nginx-how-to-reroute-specifically

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Option `root /var/www/letsencrypt/;` tells to nginx "this is base directory", so final path will be `/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/`.

So, you have 2 options:

1. Change your path, for example to

   ```
   $ echo hi > /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/hi
   ```
2. Change behavior of nginx, so nginx will treat it as alias:

   ```
   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
     default_type "text/plain";
     rewrite /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*) /$1 break;
     root /var/www/letsencrypt;
   }
   ```

And don't forget make `killall -1 nginx` to reload config

Comment: What does `killall -1` do?

Comment: Instead of `killall -1 nginx` to reload config. You can do `sudo nginx -t` to verify the config and if that returns successful, the perform a `sudo service Nginx restart`

Comment: `killall -1` send signal `SIGHUP`, which means "reload your config ASAP" for most daemons (not for all). All running daemons with specified name (nginx in our case) will reload configs. This good practice, when you have multiple instances of nginx (or any other daemon), with different configs. In my usually setup `nginx -t` or `service Nginx restart` will do nothing, as nginx can be in different directories, even not in `$PATH` and system knows nothing about it.

Comment: But you still want to test your config before reloading, so you need to know where those binaries are anyways. It would be safer to loop over the binaries and call `NGINX_BIN -t && NGINX_BIN -s reload`.

Comment: what about using `systemctl restart nginx`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Synology Nginx configuration now has a rule for acme-challenge. Put your file in `/var/lib/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge` and there is no need to reload Nginx as the configuration stay unchanged.

See `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using root and not alias, i have this as working solution:

```
listen       80;
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  alias /var/www/acme;
}
location / {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```